# How often is SIGHUP called in this situation?

Tags: linux, debian, signals

I have situation where I am connected to my BeagleBone Black over USB cable, and I started my application in Linux terminal and I'm watching its execution, it sends me some data to terminal and it expects some inputs all the time.

What happens if, while application is still running, I unplug USB cable from my PC.

How long it will run on that way?

Will SIGHUP kill my application after some time because there is no USB connection?

How often SIGHUP is sent to system, and what it represents?

How SIGHUP is related to DCD (Data Carrie Detect)?

Comment: Which shell are you running?

Comment: Bash Shell - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)

Comment: Is your USB cable a USB-to-serial adapter that is plugged into the USB port of the BBB and the serial port of another computer?

Comment: It is plugged into the USB port of BBB. @MarkPlotnick

Comment: I defer to someone who can test this to provide a definitive answer, but what I believe will happen if you unplug the serial cable is that (1) DCD will be deasserted (2) This will make the kernel send a SIGHUP to the foreground process group running on that port on the BBB, which will include bash and the currently-running program (3) since programs usually do not catch SIGHUP, the running program will likely be terminated (4) bash does catch SIGHUP, and sends SIGHUP to each of its child processes that are still alive (unless you have run the `disown` command).

Comment: I assumed that situation, because my app after some time get killed, and I think that is the reason. No my app is not disowned so it is getting killed by SIGHUP. @MarkPlotnick

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question you asked a few hours ago in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230348/how-often-is-sighup-called-in-this-situation?